# Detect if a device has access to Huawei App Gallery with Cordova

Tags: cordova, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

In Cordova, how do I detect if a device has the Huawei App Gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are advised to add **cordova-plugin-appavailability** in **cordova plugin**, and then check whether the AppGallery package exists.

```
appAvailability.check("com.huawei.appmarket",function () {
alert('Huawei App market exist');
},function () {
alert('There is no Huawei App market');
});
```